# EWS - How to search for items [message] between dates?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to search for message items between two dates from the inbox folder.
I use the following restrictionType but it throws this error:

**firmt.RootFolder = null**

What am I doing wrong?

There is some messages between the mentionned dates ;-)

Thanks for your suggestions.

```
        using (ExchangeServiceBinding esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding())
        {
            esb.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExchangeWebServicesURL"].ToString();
            esb.RequestServerVersionValue = new RequestServerVersion();
            esb.RequestServerVersionValue.Version = ExchangeVersionType.Exchange2007_SP1;
            esb.PreAuthenticate = true;
            esb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
            FindItemType findItemRequest = new FindItemType();
            // paging
            IndexedPageViewType ipvt = new IndexedPageViewType();
            ipvt.BasePoint = IndexBasePointType.Beginning;
            ipvt.MaxEntriesReturned = nombreMessage;
            ipvt.MaxEntriesReturnedSpecified = true;
            ipvt.Offset = offset;
            findItemRequest.Item = ipvt;
            // filter by dates
            AndType andType = new AndType();
            List<SearchExpressionType> searchExps = new List<SearchExpressionType>();
            RestrictionType restriction = new RestrictionType();
            PathToUnindexedFieldType pteft = new PathToUnindexedFieldType
            {
                FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.itemDateTimeSent
            };
            IsGreaterThanOrEqualToType IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo = new IsGreaterThanOrEqualToType
            {
                Item = pteft,
                FieldURIOrConstant = new FieldURIOrConstantType
                {
                    Item = new ConstantValueType
                    {
                        Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6d).ToString()
                    }
                }
            };
            searchExps.Add(IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo);

            IsLessThanOrEqualToType IsLessThanOrEqualTo = new IsLessThanOrEqualToType
            {
                Item = pteft,
                FieldURIOrConstant = new FieldURIOrConstantType
                {
                    Item = new ConstantValueType
                    {
                        Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1d).ToString()
                    }
                }
            };
            searchExps.Add(IsLessThanOrEqualTo);
            andType.Items = searchExps.ToArray();
            restriction.Item = andType;
            findItemRequest.Restriction = restriction;
            //// Define the sort order of items.
            FieldOrderType[] fieldsOrder = new FieldOrderType[1];
            fieldsOrder[0] = new FieldOrderType();
            PathToUnindexedFieldType dateOrder = new PathToUnindexedFieldType
            {
                FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.itemDateTimeReceived
            };
            fieldsOrder[0].Item = dateOrder;
            fieldsOrder[0].Order = SortDirectionType.Descending;
            findItemRequest.SortOrder = fieldsOrder;
            findItemRequest.Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow;
            // define which item properties are returned in the response 
            findItemRequest.ItemShape = new ItemResponseShapeType
            {
                BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly
            };
            // identify which folder to search 
            DistinguishedFolderIdType[] folderIDArray = new DistinguishedFolderIdType[1];
            folderIDArray[0] = new DistinguishedFolderIdType { Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.inbox };
            // add folders to request 
            findItemRequest.ParentFolderIds = folderIDArray;
            // find the messages 
            FindItemResponseType findItemResponse = esb.FindItem(findItemRequest);
            //-------------
            ArrayOfResponseMessagesType responseMessages = findItemResponse.ResponseMessages;
            ResponseMessageType responseMessage = responseMessages.Items[0];
            if (responseMessage is FindItemResponseMessageType)
            {
                FindItemResponseMessageType firmt = (responseMessage as FindItemResponseMessageType);
         *******FindItemParentType fipt = firmt.RootFolder;********
                object obj = fipt.Item;
                // FindItem contains an array of items.
                ArrayOfRealItemsType realitems = (obj as ArrayOfRealItemsType);
                ItemType[] items = realitems.Items;
                // if no messages were found, then return null -- we're done 
                if (items == null || items.Count() <= 0)
                    return null;
                // FindItem never gets "all" the properties, so now that we've found them all, we need to get them all. 
                BaseItemIdType[] itemIds = new BaseItemIdType[items.Count()];
                for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
                    itemIds[i] = items[i].ItemId;
                GetItemType getItemType = new GetItemType
                {
                    ItemIds = itemIds,
                    ItemShape = new ItemResponseShapeType
                    {
                        BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties,
                        BodyType = BodyTypeResponseType.Text,
                        BodyTypeSpecified = true,
                        AdditionalProperties = new BasePathToElementType[] { 
                            new PathToUnindexedFieldType { FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.itemDateTimeSent },
                            new PathToUnindexedFieldType { FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.messageFrom },
                            new PathToUnindexedFieldType { FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.messageIsRead },
                            new PathToUnindexedFieldType { FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.messageSender },
                            new PathToUnindexedFieldType { FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.messageToRecipients },
                            new PathToUnindexedFieldType { FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.messageCcRecipients },
                            new PathToUnindexedFieldType { FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.messageBccRecipients }
                        }
                    }
                };
                GetItemResponseType getItemResponse = esb.GetItem(getItemType);
                messages = ReadItems(getItemResponse, items.Count());
            }
```

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown?  This is an awful lot of code.  You need to be able to identify where the problem is occurring rather than posting your entire program.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, but since I didn't know where the problem was I posted the whole bunch of code. 
The exception is located after the line with stars ********** and the value of fipt is null.
After a deep debug session I found that responseMessage.MessageText has the following content "The specified value is invalid for property." and the specified value is "FieldURI". here is the MessageXml property value: <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DateTimeSent" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" /> And the value is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer on my own after a long search about date format.

The restrictions has to be defined as this:

```
// greater or equal to 
string dateStart = DateTime.Today.add(-6d);
string dateEnd = DateTime.Today.Add(1d);

PathToUnindexedFieldType dateSentPath = new PathToUnindexedFieldType();
dateSentPath.FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.itemDateTimeSent;
IsGreaterThanOrEqualToType IsGreaterThanOrEqual = new IsGreaterThanOrEqualToType();
IsGreaterThanOrEqual.Item = dateSentPath;
FieldURIOrConstantType dateConstant = new FieldURIOrConstantType();
ConstantValueType dateConstantValue = new ConstantValueType();
dateConstantValue.Value = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}T00:00:00Z", dateStart.Year.ToString(), dateStart.Month.ToString(), dateStart.Day.ToString());
dateConstant.Item = dateConstantValue;
IsGreaterThanOrEqual.FieldURIOrConstant = dateConstant;

// less than or equal to
PathToUnindexedFieldType dateSentPath1 = new PathToUnindexedFieldType();
dateSentPath1.FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.itemDateTimeSent;
IsLessThanOrEqualToType lessThanOrEqualTo = new IsLessThanOrEqualToType();
lessThanOrEqualTo.Item = dateSentPath1;
FieldURIOrConstantType dateConstant1 = new FieldURIOrConstantType();
ConstantValueType dateConstantValue1 = new ConstantValueType();
dateConstantValue1.Value = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}T00:00:00Z", dateEnd.Year.ToString(), dateEnd.Month.ToString(), dateEnd.Day.ToString());
dateConstant1.Item = dateConstantValue1;
lessThanOrEqualTo.FieldURIOrConstant = dateConstant1;

RestrictionType restriction = new RestrictionType();
AndType andType = new AndType();
andType.Items = new SearchExpressionType[] { lessThanOrEqualTo, IsGreaterThanOrEqual };
restriction.Item = andType;
findItemRequest.Restriction = restriction;
```

Hope this help someone some day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this in the future, EWS has gotten even more strict about date formatting. The accepted answer formatting works for 2 digit months, but it does not for single digit months.

The formatting that works in all cases is:

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(15).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The restriction also works using the "Sortable date/time pattern".

```
Datetime.Now.ToString("s")
```